# How to find which alias was used

Tags: bash, alias

I am using two aliases for same function say

```
alias lsd=LSD
alias lsdr=LSD
function LSD {

}
```

Now I need to check in function if lsd alias was used run ls -ld or if lsdr was used run ls -ldr with the arguments passed.

I can use the parameters but I want to detect the alias within a function, that from which alias was it invoked.

Comment: Can you add more information, what causes one alias to run over another?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: You could use arguments. i.e. `alias lsd=LSD 1 ; alias lsdr=LSD 2; LSD () { if [ "$1" -eq 1 ]; then echo "lsd"; else echo "lsdr"; fi }`

Comment: Thank you guys for your repsonse,

Aserre, if the 1/2 is passed as argument then $* wont work, and $* is required
123, any particular reason why I should not?

dood, I was making aliases and came up with idea to differentiate base on the alias used, so that I can pass another info in arguments.

Comment: Aserre, thanks for the suggestion, only work around found so far is to skip first argument and the process the rest of the arguments, 

Still I will keep looking to find the way to differentiate the alias.

Answer (score 1):

Just set up your aliases to include an additional argument to identify the alias that was used, and within the function, shift that argument from the argument list.

```
function LSD
{
    typeset version=${1}
    shift

    case ${version} in
        1) echo "called as lsd" ;;
        2) echo "called as lsdr" ;;
    esac

    echo "Other args = $*"
}

alias lsd="LSD 1"
alias lsdr="LSD 2"
```